# My mobile menu is being hidden by page content

Tags: css, z-index

Page content is covering the mobile menu [on our site](http://plumscafe.com/the-cafe/). Make your browser smaller, if needed, to see the problem.

I searched quite a bit and read a bunch of forum posts, so, I've tried playing with z-index and position:relative and I deleted a body tag with overflow-x:hidden, but I am not getting any results.

Here is the CSS I am currently using

```
.cshero-mobile-menu  { position:relative; z-index:20000; }
.cshero-mobile-menu a { position:relative; z-index:21000; }
.cshero-mobile-menu span { position:relative; z-index:22000; }
.article * {position:relative; z-index:1000;}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and advise me how to fix it?

Thank You!

Comment: Visiting your site gets me `Your access to this site has been limited
Your access to this service has been temporarily limited. Please try again in a few minutes. (HTTP response code 503)

Reason: Access from your area has been temporarily limited for security reasons.`

Comment: Sorry, that must have been when I was testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following `z-index` rule to fix your issue:

```
#cs-header-custom-bottom .container {
    …
    z-index: 11;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the element that needed to be targeted. At first it didn't work, but I changed to a higher z-index and it did. I still have a couple of pages that aren't working right, but, I think there is another problem on those pages so will work that out first. Thank you!!